# How to apply bitwise-like XOR between lists of different lengths?

Tags: python

What i would like to do is to initialize an array which has 5 elements set to 0 and then copy the other array to the first one, something like this:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 2, 3]
print a | b
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

Is there any pythonic way in doing so except:

```
for i, x in enumerate(b):
    a[i] = x
```

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that buffer `a` will always be filled with plain zeroes at the beginning and condition `len(b) < len(a)` is always `true`, also in each case buffer `a` will always start getting overwritten from index `0`.

Ill explain why i need this kind of behaviour in the first place, basicly I have a raw 256-byte UDP frame. Buffer `a` corresponds to bytes 16-31 in the frame. Depending on some conditions, those bytes will either be overwritten or be set at 0, length of `b` is always 12.

```
def foo(b=12*[0]):
    a = 16*[0]
    return a[:12] = b[:]
```

Comment: What output do you expect for `a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: Hope 'edit' section clarifes a little bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a[:len(b)] = b[:]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I don't think that works. What if `a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` ? Your output would also be `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]`. But `[1, 1, 3, 0, 0]` would probably be the correct answer. At least that is how I understand the question.

Comment: @miindlek: The question has conflicting criteria. I decided to fulfill the "copy the other array to the first one" criterion based on the second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Python 2:

```
import itertools
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 2, 3]
g = (l | r for (l, r) in itertools.izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0))
print list(g)
```

And this in Python 3:

```
import itertools
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 2, 3]
g = (l | r for (l, r) in itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0))
print(list(g))
```

I created a generator `g` but if you know in advance you want all values of it already, then it's okay to have a list comprehension right away instead.

This is the doc for `zip_longest`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Directly with the list comprehension (py3):

```
import itertools
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 2, 3]
g = [l | r for (l, r) in itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]
print(g)
```

Comment: why not make `g` a listcomp?

Comment: @e.s. You were faster than my edit :-). I explained in here the reason. I'll edit again to make it more obvious.

Comment: And I realized that my answer is about the title of the question, whereas @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams 's answer is closer the the actual needs.

Comment: @SamuelGIFFARD Maybe the title of the question should be edited so it matches the OP's actual question. Otherwise it will mislead future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Why waste time defining `a` in the first place? You can simply append the correct number of `0`s to `b` instead:

```
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = b + [0] * (5 - len(b))
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (Note: XOR operator is `^` ?

```
import itertools

a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 2, 3]

def safeXOR(arr1, arr2):
    return list((x ^ y for (x, y) in itertools.zip_longest(arr1, arr2, fillvalue=0)))

print(safeXOR(a,b))
```